# Как ставить urlTemplate вместо тегов

Tags: javascript, html5, angularjs

Добрый день.
Ситуация такая. Нужно вместо `mainform.innerHtml = '<p>sala</p>'`ставить шаблон`mainform.innerHtml='template.html'` где внутри `template.html` написан тот же `'<p>sala</p>'` ??

```
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myfunction = function () {
        var text_1 = document.getElementById('text_1').value;
        var mainform = document.getElementById('mainform');
        if (text_1 == 's') {
            mainform.innerHTML = '<p>sala</p>'
        }
        else {
            alert("error");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос задан конечно сумбурно.

Весь шаблонный `HTML`, который Вы хотите вынести в отдельные файлы, следует делать внутри директив.

Именно для этого они существует в Angular, собственно в директивах заключена главная сила Angular.

**JS**

```
app.directive('directiveName', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // переменная из общего/родительского скопа Вашего контроллера
            scope.mainform = 'someVariable';
        },
        templateUrl: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // задаем шаблон по условию
            // это правильно и удобнее делать здесь (например если нужно будет задавать шаблон динамически)
            if (scope.text_1 == 's') {
                return 'pages/1.html'
            } else if (scope.text_1 == 'ss') {
                return 'pages/2.html'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**template.html**

```
<div class="someClass">
    <span class="anotherClass">
        {{mainform}} <!-- переменная из контроллера -->
        <!-- 
            внутри шаблона директивы можете использовать 
            любые переменные из родительского скопа контроллера 
        -->
    </span>
</div>
```

**HTML**

```
<directiveName class="someClass" id="someId">
        <!-- внутри директивы будет отрендерен template.html -->
</directiveName>
```

Comment: Я хотел сделать по другому, у меня один button где после проверки должен показывать определенный шаблон. Код щас ставлю

Comment: var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.changeTemplate = function () {
        var text_1 = document.getElementById('text_1').value;
        if (text_1 == 's') {
            $scope.template = 'pages/1.html';
        }
        else if(text_1=='ss'){
            $scope.template = 'pages/2.html';
        }
    }
});

Comment: @MuhammadYakubov, взгляните на обновленный ответ. В директиве можно задать шаблон по условию, если это необходимо. Используя директивы, Вы получаете возможность более гибко писать, а это может в дальнейшем понадобится. Нужно привыкать к использованию директив. Это правильный, так называемый, `angular-way` кодинг)

Answer (score 1):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.changeTemplate = function () {
        var text_1 = document.getElementById('text_1').value;
        if (text_1 == 's') {
            $scope.template = 'pages/1.html';
        }
        else if(text_1=='ss'){
            $scope.template = 'pages/2.html';
        }
    }
});
```

а в html

```
<div data-ng-include="template"></div>
```

Comment: <div data-ng-include="template"></div>

Comment: Все это создал не используя директиву)

Comment: пожалуйста взгляните на обновленный ответ.

Comment: Да, точно. Проверил с директивами удобнее работать. Спасибо